# LINQ to Lookup with distinct items and count

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

If I define a list as

```
public class ItemsList
{
    public string structure { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public double Dim { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Element { get; set; }
}

List<ItemsList> _itemsList = new List<ItemsList>();
```

I'm trying to get the a distinct count of structures in a Lookup with structure as the key and count of structure as the value.

At the moment I have

```
var sCount = from p in _itemsList
    group p by p.Structure into g
    select new { Structure = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

but this just returns the data as an anonymous type. Can someone please help me with the syntax to get this into a Lookup using `.ToLookup`?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - a lookup has *several values* per key. That's the point of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *suspect* you actually want:

```
var lookup = _itemsList.ToLookup(p => p.Structure);
```

You can still count the items for any group:

```
foreach (var group in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", group.Key, group.Count());
}
```

... but you've also got the *values* within each group.

If you *really* just want the count, then it sounds like you don't want a lookup at all - you want a `Dictionary`, which you can get with:

```
var dictionary = _itemsList.GroupBy(p => p.Structure)
                           .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```